# how i can pass a file directory (path) as parameter?

Tags: windows, bash, unix, command-line, batch-file

how i can pass a file directory (path) as parameter to 
1. batch file in windows operating system
2. bash file in unix oprating system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Batch files can only handle parameters %0 to %9

%0 is the program name as it was called,
%1 is the first command line parameter,
%2 is the second command line parameter,
and so on till %9.
```

For Batch check @ http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

For shell script check @ http://docsrv.sco.com:507/en/OSUserG/_Passing_to_shell_script.html

Answer (score 2):

With windows batch file, you use `%1` (`%2`, `%3` etc). With Bash, you use `$1` (`$2`,`$3`...).

Answer (score 1):

1) To a Windows batch file:

```
script.bat C:\some\path
```

To access the path in the script use %1:

```
echo %1
```

2) To a bash shell script:

```
script.sh /some/path
```

To access the path in the script use $1:

```
echo $1
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, you use `$1` to get the first parameter. You're saying it has to be a path to directory, so you may want to try the following:

```
test -d $1 && echo "Directory exists"
```